# How to identify task when reporting progress after launching multiple tasks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library

I use [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) to report Task action in a Winforms application. I am not sure how to report the task identity so that the UI can act accordingly, ie, add item to tab page 1 if task 1 returned a result, and add item to tab page 2, if task 2 returned a result.

I am using a foreach loop to create tasks, which all do the same thing. I need task identity based on the order when the task was created, ie, when first task is created, the UI knows it's "task 1" that reports back information, and so on. The number of tasks is created based on the number of the loop, which may change.

At first I thought Task.Id can be used to identify the task. But according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.id(v=vs.110).aspx) , Task IDs are assigned on-demand and do not necessarily represent the order in which task instances are created. And task identifiers are not guaranteed to be unique.

I use `Progress` as indicated in this [tutorial](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html).

Comment: If you want to do two different things when two different things report progress, create two `Progress` instances, and give the right instance to the right operation reporting progress.

Comment: It would be much easier if I can get the task information.

Comment: @oopsdazie no, what makes you think that? Tasks are no more identifiable that lambda or function **calls**. They are *not* threads. If you want to pass data to the UI, create a class to use as the progress DTO and pass the type of data you want into it. It's a *LOT* easier to update the proper UI element when you pass all the required information  in the progress object

Comment: As for multiple Progress instances, why not? Tasks are *always* created dynamically. You can't reuse a task. You *always* create a new task and when that runs, it's destroyed. You *can* reuse a single Progress instance, from multiple tasks. You *can* create multiple instances, with different callbacks.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 3 When you create a task, if you use Progress report, don't you need to create an instance, and pass the instance into the task to report? I am re-using one class for all tasks, then if I use multiple progress instances, I need to have a class that can take indefinite amount of progress instances.

Comment: @oopsdazie no, that's not how it's used. Just like a CancellationToken, you create *one* instance at the "root" and you *pass it around* to any method that wants to use it. You *don't* create a new instance for each task. Check [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

Comment: @oopsdazie the Progress class will call its callback or raise its event on the thread that created it. If you create it *inside* a task, it can't update the UI. You create the Progress<T> instance on the UI thread and pass it as an `IProgress<T>` to every *method* that wants to report progress. It doesn't matter whether that method is called by a Task, an event handler on the UI thread or by another method

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 3  My problem is more with task identity. I am sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question. And I've found a solution. When I have time, I will post it. I don't know how good my solution is....lol

Comment: @oopsdazie I've been through SSIS version hell too. At least now I no longer have to open both VS versions to work. Divide-and-conquer is the best option when the problem isn't *obvious*.

Comment: @oopsdazie furthermore, all components are either *COM* or *.NET* components. The dtsx elements often contain the COM ID, Class ID or type names of the components. If you can isolate the difference you can search the registry or the component folder to find what's missing, what's different

Comment: The tutorial you linked to *doesn't* create a new instance for each task. It creates a new instance when a button is pressed, before the task even starts. Not that it matters. *The progress DTO* should contain enough information to do whatever you want it to do. The task ID doesn't matter *at all*.

Comment: It's Servy, who told me to create multiple instances of Progress in the first comment. I just use one progress for reporting all tasks information. My problem is more with how to report back the task identity through only one progress instance.

Comment: @oopsdazie you keep confusing different things. **Why** do you think you need to know the task ID at all? Not that there *is* one - tasks themselves don't run. *Threads* run. The task isn't going to be around for that ID to matter.

Comment: @oopsdazie chatting isn't going to help. It won't help anyone who has a similar problem in the future. Post what you want to do in the question itself. If you use a loop, you already have a *counter* that you can use as a "task ID". If you use LINQ, you can use the `Select(T,Int32)` overload that passes the index.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Your last comment gave me some light. I will post my detailed solution later. I will be using the counter to identify the thread. If you re-word your comment, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I essentially increase an count within the loop. Pass that count to each task I created and report back the number to UI. Here is the step:

First, I pass the count into the tasks:

```
//Create the taskId count
int taskId = 0;
//Create a blank list of tasks
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
//Progress instance to show task result when task is still runnning
var progressReport = new Progress<ActionLog>((actionLog) => reportOfficeName(actionLog));
foreach (var datalist in bigDataList) 
{                   
    try
    {
        taskId++; //Increase the count
        Task task = new Task((Object obj) => {
            /// Need to cast the passed in task id to integer
            int id = (int)obj;
            RandomMethod(datalist, progressReport, cancellationToken, _setting, id);

        }, taskId, cancellationToken); //Pass the id into task

        task.Start();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException("Task cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
} 
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Then, to get the id, I just report the id:

```
Private void RandomMethod (List<Data> datalist,IProgress<ActionLog> progress, CancellationToken token, int taskId ){
    foreach (var data in datalist){
        //report the taskId along with other parameters back to UI 
        progress.Report(new ActionLog() { TaskId = taskId });
    }
}
```